# similar to the Magento2 - Fail

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, marketplace

I've created an extension which I uploaded on marketplace for technical review. I got the following response in technical submission:

```
Review Results:

Tech: Code quality issues: CPD: This extension contains duplicated code.

vendor/MCB/CreditmemoCronTime.php - similar to the Magento2 - Fail
magento/module-backup/magento-module-backup-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Config/Backend/Cron.php
vendor/MCB/ContactsCronTime.php - similar to the Magento2 - Fail
magento/module-backup/magento-module-backup-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Config/Backend/Cron.php
vendor/MCB/InvoicesCronTime.php - similar to the Magento2 - Fail
magento/module-backup/magento-module-backup-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Config/Backend/Cron.php
vendor/MCB/ItemsCronTime.php - similar to the Magento2 - Fail
magento/module-backup/magento-module-backup-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Config/Backend/Cron.php
```

> ContactsCronTime.php file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Test\Model\Config\Backend;

class ContactsCronTime extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    /**
     * Cron string path variable
     */
    const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/default/jobs/test_contacts_job/schedule/cron_expr';

    /**
     * Cron model path variable
     */
    const CRON_MODEL_PATH = 'crontab/default/jobs/test_contacts_job/run/model';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory
     */
    protected $_configValueFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_runModelPath = '';

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param string $runModelPath
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        $runModelPath = '',
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_runModelPath = $runModelPath;
        $this->_configValueFactory = $configValueFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function afterSave()
    {
        $time = $this->getData('groups/synchronization/groups/test_contacts/fields/cron_time/value');

        // phpcs:disable
        if ($time == '60') {
            $time = 0;
            $cronExprArray = [
                intval($time), //Minute
                '*', //Hour
                '*', //Day of the Month
                '*', //Month of the Year
                '*', //Day of the Week
            ];
        } elseif ($time == '120') {
            $time = 2;
            $cronExprArray = [
                '0', //Minute
                '*/'.intval($time), //Hour
                '*', //Day of the Month
                '*', //Month of the Year
                '*', //Day of the Week
            ];
        } else {
            $cronExprArray = [
                '*/'.intval($time), //Minute
                '*', //Hour
                '*', //Day of the Month
                '*', //Month of the Year
                '*', //Day of the Week
            ];
        }

        $cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);

        try {
            $this->_configValueFactory->create()->load(
                self::CRON_STRING_PATH,
                'path'
            )->setValue(
                $cronExprString
            )->setPath(
                self::CRON_STRING_PATH
            )->save();
            $this->_configValueFactory->create()->load(
                self::CRON_MODEL_PATH,
                'path'
            )->setValue(
                $this->_runModelPath
            )->setPath(
                self::CRON_MODEL_PATH
            )->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception(__('We can\'t save the cron expression.'));
        }
        // phpcs:enable

        return parent::afterSave();
    }
}
```

> Although core file and mine file code is totally different.

Can anyone explain what is the meaning of this error and how can I fix this to resubmit it again for technical review?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the duplicated code of Magento core class

```
magento/module-backup/magento-module-backup-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Config/Backend/Cron.php
```

in your following classes

```
vendor/MCB/CreditmemoCronTime.php
vendor/MCB/ContactsCronTime.php
vendor/MCB/InvoicesCronTime.php
vendor/MCB/ItemsCronTime.php
```

you need to extend your classes from Magento core class instead of duplicating its code

**EDIT**

please check it your code is duplicated with the core file

[image]

Comment: My custom file code is totally different  from magento core file. Only 1 thing is similar between mine and that core file. We both are extending same class.

Comment: then you should extend with the core class instead of extending it with the other class which the core class is already extended to

Comment: I am not using `magento-module-backup` module in my extension anywhere then why should i extend it's class. And as i also checked many core files which are also extending that core class which I and  `magento-module-backup-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Config/Backend/Cron.php` module-backup file using then why marketplace technical review showing only `module-backup` class as duplicate.

Comment: can you share the code of your class

Comment: I have updated code in my question. Please check.

Comment: Most of your code is duplicated with the core file kindly check it again check the screenshot in my answer

Comment: This core file code is also seems to same as mine `vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Log/Cron.php` then i don't understand why marketplace is comparing my code with `module-backup` file and why not comparing with this   `module-config`

Comment: I think they have automated system which compare the code, but you should avoid duplicating the code

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you have any suggestion, how I can remove duplicate code and can optimize mine code?

Comment: simply extend the class, whose code you are duplicating and use the function you want